# evernote API with opauth authentication

Tags: php, evernote

I need to integrate [evernote](http://dev.evernote.com/) in my application.  I need to implement authentication using [opauth](https://github.com/evernote/opauth-evernote).
I have downloaded evetnote api and everntoe strategy.
 I need to authenticate a user and get token and then making calls, but there is error happening in authentication, below is the error
[image: Error].

Below is the directory structure which i installed using composer and strategy i installed from git. 
[image: Directory structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my apache rewrite_module. after i enable module for apache. it worked and i was able to fetch token and user data from evernote.